# How to get the original cp values from rpart object

Tags: r, cp, rpart, pruning

My aim is to prune a deep tree according to a certain value of the cost-complexity parameter, say 3.

I like growing trees with `rpart()`, in particular for the possibility of customizing plots. However, the cost-complexity parameter `cp` is rescaled to signal how much the lack of fit is decreased at each split, thus assuming values in the interval [0, 1]. Similar reasoning applies for `prune.rpart()`.

So, pruning according to a chosen values, say again 3, is infeasible - more precisely, leads to no split at all.

The following procedure is the only way I found to achieve my aim:

1. Grow a deep tree with `tree()`.
2. Prune using `prune.tree()` or `cv.tree()` (depending on your aim).
3. Look for the size of the pruned tree, or for the size with the lowest cross-validated error if you used `cv.tree()` in step 2.
4. Grow a deep tree with `rpart()`.
5. Use the `cptable` output to extract the `cp` value leading to the size found in step 4.
6. Use `prune.rpart()` passing the `cp` from step 5.

Is there a way to avoid all these steps? Ideally, I would get the non-rescaled `cp` values from `cptable`. Clearly, other roads would be well accepted, if working.

I attach a minimal working example illustrating the procedure mentioned above:

```
library(tree)
library(rpart)

# Simulating data.
set.seed(1986)

X = matrix(rnorm(2000, 0, 1), nrow = 1000, ncol = 2) 
epsilon = matrix(rnorm(1000, 0, 0.01), nrow = 1000)

y = X[, 1] + X[, 2] + epsilon

dta = data.frame(X, y)

# Step 1.
my.tree = tree(y ~ X1 + X2, data = dta)

# Step 2.
cv.prune = cv.tree(my.tree)

# Step 3.
best.size = cv.prune$size[which.min(cv.prune$dev)]

# Step 4.
tree.rpart = rpart(y ~ X1 + X2, data = dta, method = "anova") 

# Step 5.
best.cp = tree.rpart$cptable[, 1][tree.rpart$cptable[, "nsplit"] == cv.f.leaves - 1]

# Step 6.
cv.prune.rpart = prune.rpart(tree.rpart, best.cp)

# Double-Check.
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(prune.tree(my.tree3, best = best.size))
plot(cv.prune.rpart)
```

Comment: Maybe [this CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117908/rpart-complexity-parameter-confusion)  can be of help.

Answer (score 1):

The unscaled complexity parameter can be retrieved from the `summary` object:

```
RelErr <- my.tree$cptable[, 3]
smry <- summary(my.tree)

(CP <- -diff(RelErr))
#         2          3          4          5          6          7          8 
#0.36836935 0.15484483 0.13959316 0.04950422 0.03587252 0.02540786 0.02278527 

smry$cptable[, 1]
#         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8 
#0.36836935 0.15484483 0.13959316 0.04950422 0.03587252 0.02540786 0.02278527 0.01000000
```

See the package vignette [longintro](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf), and these CV posts [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117908/rpart-complexity-parameter-confusion), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113097/how-are-cp-cost-complexity-values-calculated-in-rpart-or-decision-trees-in-ge) for the formula and more information.

Comment: Sorry, but I am confused by your answer. I was aware of the posts you suggest, but I did not find the asnwer I am looking for there. Moreover, running `identical(smry$cptable, my.tree$cptable)` gives TRUE. How is `smry$cptable` providing additional information?
Anyway, I am going to edit the question to be more clear.